# Creating an SQLite trigger that updates bank account based on transaction information upon insert

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, triggers

I have an Android application that helps the user keep track of their finances. The application has a database that stores account and transaction information. Each time a transaction is recorded I also have to update the account table to adjust that account's balance, as well as it's remaining allowance for a certain spending period. The accounts table looks like this:

```
| id | name | balance | allowance | allowanceRemaining | spendingPeriod |
```

And a transaction table that looks like this:

```
| id | description | amount | withdrawal | discretionary | accountID |
```

Withdrawal and discretionary are both integers that are 0 or 1 to act as booleans. I have tried the following to at least set the balance based on if a transaction was a withdrawal or not but I am getting syntax errors and I can't figure out why. Even beyond syntax, though, I am having trouble understanding the logic and created the proper case statements.

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_account AFTER INSERT ON transactions
BEGIN
  UPDATE accounts a SET a.balance = 
    (CASE WHEN new.withdrawal = 1 THEN a.balance - new.amount ELSE
     a.balance + new.amount END) WHERE a.id = new.accountID;
END;
```

In pseudocode, what I would like to do is:

- If the transaction is a deposit, add the money
- If the transaction is a withdrawal, check if it is discretionary
- If it is discretionary, remove from the balance and the allowance remaining
- If it is not, remove only from the balance.

I made an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/fb318/1), that has some quick sample data but no trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE wants the new value for each changed column, so you have to formulate your requirements this way:

The balance

- increases by the amount for a deposit,
- decreases by the amount for a withdrawal.

The remaining allowance

- decreases by the amount for a discetionary withdrawal.

As for the syntax, you cannot use an alias for the UPDATEd table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_account
AFTER INSERT ON transactions
BEGIN
    UPDATE accounts
    SET balance = CASE
                  WHEN new.withdrawal THEN balance - new.amount
                  ELSE                     balance + new.amount
                  END,
        allowanceRemaining = CASE
                             WHEN new.withdrawal AND new.discretionary
                             THEN allowanceRemaining - new.amount
                             ELSE allowanceRemaining
                             END
    WHERE id = NEW.accountID;
END;
```

It might be simpler to use the WHEN clause of the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_balance_for_deposit
AFTER INSERT ON transactions
WHEN NOT NEW.withdrawal
BEGIN
    UPDATE accounts
    SET balance = balance + NEW.amount
    WHERE id = NEW.accountID;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER update_balance_for_withdrawal
AFTER INSERT ON transactions
WHEN NEW.withdrawal
BEGIN
    UPDATE accounts
    SET balance = balance - NEW.amount
    WHERE id = NEW.accountID;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER update_allowance_for_discretionary_withdrawal
AFTER INSERT ON transactions
WHEN NEW.withdrawal AND NEW.discretionary
BEGIN
    UPDATE accounts
    SET allowanceRemaining = allowanceRemaining - NEW.amount
    WHERE id = NEW.accountID;
END;
```

Comment: That was a good idea to use three different triggers, I didn't think about that. I'm getting a syntax error in SQL Fiddle but I can't see why. I'll try and implement it into the app and let you know how it runs.