# Postdating transactions for a bank database

Tags: android, android-sqlite, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I have a financial tracking application where the user can enter transactions for their bank accounts and keep track of spending. I have implemented the triggers I learned from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27372310/creating-an-sqlite-trigger-that-updates-bank-account-based-on-transaction-inform) question to automatically update the account balance whenever a transaction is inserted. I also have triggers for edits, deletions, etc.

The issue that has come up with this is that it does not take the date into consideration. If the user enters a transaction for a month in advance, their account balance is still adjusted. I would like to have a way to make it so the account balance isn't adjusted until that day.

To start, I can write my triggers to only update if the transaction date is today or earlier, but then I need to update the account balance when the time comes. How can I do that?

To answer the "what have you tried" question, I'm not really sure what to try. I have considered setting an alarm to run on a specific date and time, but I'm not sure how to do that properly and make sure that the alarm only runs once. Also, if the user enters multiple transactions that are post-dated, and I create several alarms, I am afraid that will be a battery killer.

How could I implement an alarm to accomplish this in an efficient manner?

Answer (score 1):

You could store the date that the balance was last updated in a table or a user preference. Then, each time the user enters the screen, you can very quickly check if the last balance update is before today. After that, you can run a query to update the balance by the transactions between last update and today.

This avoids both needlessly calculating the balance if the user isn't looking at it anyway (which an alarm would do) and calculating the balance on-the-fly each time the screen is opened (which would be pretty straight forward but wastes time if the table is any significant size).

Comment: Thank you for touching on the on-the-fly approach. I did consider that, but knew it would (eventually) become costly, and forgot to put it in my question. I will try to implement a check like you've mentioned and let you know how it works.

Comment: Question, if you don't mind. In the Accounts activity, I use an adapter to fill a ListView with the accounts info. While it would be best to check for all accounts together (which might be some complicated logic), the simplest approach would be to check each account inside the adapter (perhaps in `BindView` somehow. Do you think that'd be too costly? Realistically, the user won't have a large number of accounts.

Comment: So start an async task whenever the activity is created?